# JAX-RS, @FormParam display result in the same page

Tags: rest, post, jax-rs, response

I have this program that I am coding, the main thing is mostly to get familiar with Jax-rs and rest API. I am sending from a form in JSP page one input and with POST I pass it to my java Response class(that I use annotation @FormParam), it does what calculation I need and then I get the result in another link, what can i do to take the result just below my button on the same page? For my button function I use javascript, and when I push it I don't want to be redirected and take the result like this.

So i use this form and a javascript function in my jsp to pass the value in my POST method in java throw @FormParam

```
<form name="Form1" method="post">

    <p>
        Name : <input type="text" name="malename" id="malename" autofocus
            value="enter your name..." />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="action" id="malename" value="I'm feeling lucky"
        onclick="OnButton1();"> </form>




function OnButton1() {
        document.Form1.action = "webapi/perfectmatcher/mate"
        document.Form1.target = "_self"; // Open in a new window

        document.Form1.submit(); // Submit the page

        //return;
    }
```

Here after i have the value i use two other classes to do the calculations and return the result i need. In a few words i pass a value in my form and when i push the button i am redirected in another link(the path of POST) and i display the result. I want to display the result below my button. I hope the code is helpful and i hope i am clear with my explanation

```
@POST
@Path("/mate")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response postMaleName(@FormParam("malename") String malename) {

    String femalename = NumMatcher.numMatcher(Numberizer.numberizer(malename));

    // FemaleName female = new FemaleName(femalename);
    female.setName(femalename);
    System.out.println(female.getName());

    return Response.status(200).entity("Perfect Match for " + malename + " is " + femalename).build();

}
```

P.S.:The object female that i am trying to create its for testing purposes, i was trying somehow to get the information that i store but i cannot find how!!I used even jsp expressions but i get null value of course ...

```
<%  

    FemaleName female = new FemaleName("john");
    String string = female.getName();
    out.print(string);
%>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we have more understanding of what you're talking about.